# PHP8 connect to SQL Server DB

Tags: php, sql-server

I am facing a DB connectivity issue with PHP8 with a specific VM. I have to environments Staging and Prod. From STAGIN, I can connect to the DB hosted on PROD with both PHP7 and PHP8. When I copied the PHP directories from STAING to PROD. I can connect to PHP7 but not with PHP8.

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed
message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed
```

I am using php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_nts_x64.dll and php_sqlsrv_81_nts_x64.dll.

- There is no connectivity issue on PROD as PHP7 can connect all the time but not PHP8.
- I tried both 64 32 bit versions too but none works
- I tried using a thread-safe version for DB libraries but it didn't help

Comment: Does the problem VM have a different version of ODBC Driver for SQL Server installed on it than the working VMs? From memory PHP8 requires at least ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server (though you should really be using 17 or 18), but PHP7 still worked with ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server.

Comment: No. I have copied the same PHP directory which has all the drivers in the "ext" directory.